# how to make a create controller and its ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In the Create view, admins can create a new dish and choose its type from a drop-down list (DishTypes come from database). The problem is I don't know how to design `DishesViewModel`, `DishesController` and dropdownlist in `Create` view.

Here is ***Dishes*** model

```
public class Dishes
{ 
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public int DishID { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Dishname { get; set; }

  public int DishTypeID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("DishTypeID")]
  public virtual DishTypes DishTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is ***DishTypes*** model

```
public class DishTypes
{
    [Required]
    public int DishTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DishTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my currently Dishes view model (I use Automapoper to map them to domain models)

```
public class DishesVM
{

   [Required]
   public string DishName{ get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int DishTypeID{ get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string DishTypeName { get; set; }

}
```

This is ***DishesController***

```
public class DishesController: Controller  
{

   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
   {
      // it should  pass a list of dishTypes to my view so when admins create a dish they can choose dishtype from a dropdown list

     //I down't want to use ViewBag or ViewData
      return View()
   }
}
```

Here is ***Create*** view

```
@model  DataLayers.Models.ViewModels.DishesVM

<form  asp-controller="Dishes" asp-action="Create">
    <label class="label" asp-for="Dishname"></label>
    <input class="input" type="text" asp-for="Dishname">

    //a drop down list, which enables admins choose dishtypes, is needed here
</form
```

And finally this is ***DishRepository***

```
public class DishRepository
{
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Dishes>> GetAllDishesAsync()
     {
         return await _RepositoryContext.Set<Dishes>().ToListAsync();
     }
}
```

Feel free to change everything as u wish.

Comment: You posted a lot of code, almost none of which related to what you want. It also doesn't seem like you have tried anything at all

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Which part is unnecessary?? I tried many ways but none of them worked so I didn't add them here to keep it clear

Comment: Well, you are missing a lot of stuff. 1) The drop-down list (should be the easiest and fastest), 2) getting the DishTypes from the database, 3) consuming that from your controller and, finally, 4) pass that data to the view. Didn't anything of that work at all?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto 1)HTML of dropdown is easy but how to retrieve its data? 
2)I can get dishtypes from data base but when i pass dishesVM to view, because other fild(DishName) is NULL so the form validations warns and say dishname is required. As I metioned i'm new to it.

Comment: What is the purpose for `ProductTypeID` and `ProductTypeName`?

Comment: @TaoZhou a mistake. they should be `DishTypeID` and `DishTypeName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try steps below:

1. Change View Model

   ```
   public class DishesVM
   {

       [Required]
       public string DishName { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public int DishTypeID { get; set; }

       public List<DishTypes> DishTypes { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <form asp-action="Create">
               <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="DishName" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="DishName" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="DishName" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="DishTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
                   <select asp-for="DishTypeID"
                           class="dropdown"
                           asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DishTypes, "DishTypeID" ,"DishTypeName"))"></select>
                   <span asp-validation-for="DishTypeID" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
   {
       var types = await _context.DishTypes.ToListAsync();
       var vm = new DishesVM {
           DishTypes = types
       };
       return View(vm);
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DishesVM vm)
   {
       return Ok(vm);
   }
   ```

Comment: In your DishesVM, you added a list of DishTypes. DishTypes is a domain model and  I read somewhere that passing domain model to viewmodel is bad idea. Am I right ?

Comment: @ArianShahalami You could implement your logic to map domain model to view model, just pass a list with `DishTypeVM`.